# Difference between 'such as' and 'like'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adverbs

This one never ceases to confuse me. When to use 'such as' and when to use 'like' while giving examples? Is there any clear rule?

> - Metros like Mumbai, Delhi and Karachi are unsafe after dark.
> - Metros such as Mumbai, Delhi and Karachi are unsafe after dark.

(Before anyone points out, Delhi and Karachi are unsafe round-the-clock, but it's just an example.)

Answer (score 4):

"Such as" is more formal. However there is another subtle difference.

Consider these two examples:

> Chuck enjoys desserts such as brownies, cheesecake, and macaroons
>
> Chuck enjoys desserts like brownies, cheesecake, and macaroons

---

> Note that the second example suggests a comparison (like brownies…), whereas the first example implies inclusion (such as brownies…), and that’s precisely what is meant. In other words, many consider likeness as not being the thing itself. When you say “desserts like brownies,” you're implying that you don't enjoy brownies themselves, but instead enjoy a different dessert similar to brownies. It's a subtle difference, but one to be aware of.

Reference: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/like-versus-such-as#sthash.l8VRCYQl.dpuf

Answer (score 3):

*Such as* is preferable in formal prose, because it avoids the ambiguity that might be present with *like*. In your first sentence, a reader might briefly think that *like* was a verb. ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ puts it this way:

> The argument for **such as** was that it prevented the ambiguity that
>   might sometimes beset **like** (though the case seems to have been
>   exaggerated). Yet this concern probably explains why **such as** is
>   more than a thousand times commoner in academic writing than in
>   speech. **Such as** is also found in fiction and news writing, but
>   much less often. These facts of usage make **such as** more formal and
>   academic in style, whereas **like** is straightforward and direct.

I’m not familiar, by the way, with this use of *metro*.

Comment: My first thought was that it was *metro* in the rapid transit sense, so "...such as those in..." would be logical.  On re-reading I realise that this is the adjectival sense of *metro*, so equivalent to "metro area". I have a feeling this use of an adjective to mean an adjective qualifying a vague noun (for which I'm sure you know the term, it escapes me), is common in Indian English.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English) has this meaning listed by the way - I don't know of any decent online dictionaries for Indian English.

Comment: I guessed it was an Indian usage. Perhaps the OP can tell us.

Comment: It's an Indianism Barrie. I meant metro area or metro city, of course. I like your explanation, but don't quite agree.

What I mean is, 'It'd be great to have players like (of the caliber of) Don Bradman, Kapil Dev and Steve Waugh among the current crop of cricketers' doesn't quite mean the same as 'It'd be great to have players such as (they themselves in flesh and blood) Don Bradman, Kapil Dev and Steve Waugh...

Comment: The OED’s definition 9d of ‘such’ is: ‘Hence “such as” is used to introduce examples of a class: = for example, e.g.’

Answer (score 0):

"Like" is more informal and commonly used to emulate the spoken language, while "such as" is better to be used in the written language because it is more formal.

Furthermore, "such as" is more indicated to introduce a list of elements at least three elements that have something in common, i.e.:

> I've always loved chocolate cakes such as Sacher torte, Red Velvet and fudge cake!

Comment: What on Earth is a "saker torte"? Or do you mean Sacher?

Comment: Oh...yes it must be Sacher, I didn't know the spelling...indeed, this was not the point of the comment.

Comment: I always loved electric cars such as the one currently produced by Tesla - Only one element here

Answer (score -1):

Apologies, I am disobeying the instruction regarding how we may reply to threads here. I ask a complementary question. 
I was taught (in the US in late 1970's) that "such as" would be rather insulting to use in front of proper names. "Like" should be used when invoking selected individuals. 
Is this a (current) rule?

Comment: Due to the Q&A format of ELU, new questions should not be added as answers to existing questions. Please use the "Ask Question" button to create a new question  (with a link to this related one if you wish).