# Meaning Differences - Like x Such As

Tags: vocabulary

In order not to sound repetitive, I opted to use the word *like* as a synonym for *such as* in the following sentence:

> Second, since fuel prices have been significantly increasing, people opt for cheaper forms of urban transportation. Those options usually include the public ones - **such as** subways, buses, or trains - or alternative systems - **like** cycling, and skateboarding.

However, I've read at some websites that the word *like* might change the meaning of a sentence. They say that while the expression *such as* implies inclusion, the word *like* implies a comparison.

(https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/like-versus-such-as)

Do you think I've conveyed my ideia successfully, or should I opt for another synonym?

Please let me know if there is any other grammar, vocabulary, or meaning mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (a) Using 'such as' twice here would cause no problems. (b) Using 'like' as a synonym for 'such as' here causes no problems; the alternative 'similar to' reading  is discountable on pragmatic grounds.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with repeating *like* or *such as*. If you switch from one to the other, it might convey the impression that you think the two situations are different somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are "like" and "such as" completely synonymous?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20533/are-like-and-such-as-completely-synonymous)

Comment: On a scale between "for instance" and "resembling" we might say "Like" and "such as" do meet in the middle - as they do here - but they're not interchangeable all the way to the ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it or not, *like* is popularly used as a synonym for *such as*. In more formal writing, or in writing something to be read by a pedant, you might not want to use *like* as a synonym for *such as*. Personally I don’t like using *like* as a synonym for *such as* (and thus this is one occasion in which I agree with Quick&Dirty Tips aka Grammar Girl), but this apparently minority view cannot hold back the tide of popular usage, which is what ultimately determines “correctness”. In order to avoid immediate repetition of format without using *like* you could write **or such alternative systems as cycling and skateboarding**. This way, you’ve stayed with *such as* but used it in a different manner.

See also [Difference between ‘such as’ and ‘like’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/129976/difference-between-such-as-and-like), which doesn’t say much more than Grammar Girl or the other sites you’ve probably visited.